# How to retrieve unique rows from csv file in shell script

Tags: shell, csv

I have .csv file like this

```
1000|79|2017-01-27 16:53:00|dmp
1000|91|2017-01-27 16:53:00|cmk
1000|93|2017-01-27 16:53:00|rtf
1001|79|2017-01-27 16:58:22|dmp
1001|91|2017-01-27 16:58:22|elc
1001|93|2017-01-27 16:58:22|rtf
1002|79|2017-01-27 16:58:45|cmk
1002|91|2017-01-27 16:58:45|cmk
1003|79|2017-01-27 16:59:11|bdd
1004|79|2017-02-01 11:41:04|dmp
```

I need to make the data set like this

```
1000|79|2017-01-27 16:53:00|dmp
1001|79|2017-01-27 16:58:22|dmp
1002|79|2017-01-27 16:58:45|cmk
1003|79|2017-01-27 16:59:11|bdd
1004|79|2017-02-01 11:41:04|dmp
```

How can i do this by using shell script ??
p.s.

I am trying to do that with following command but I can not hit the bell with this though it gives unique values..

```
awk -F"|" '{print $1}' myfile.csv|sort|uniq
```

Thank you

Comment: Need more clarity in your question.your title and expecting output is conflicting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk -F"|" '{if (!a[$1]) {a[$1]=1;print $0;}}' v1
1000|79|2017-01-27 16:53:00|dmp
1001|79|2017-01-27 16:58:22|dmp
1002|79|2017-01-27 16:58:45|cmk
1003|79|2017-01-27 16:59:11|bdd
1004|79|2017-02-01 11:41:04|dmp
```

i think you need uniq the first column, right?

Comment: @Assy, please accept it as a answer if it solve your question.

Comment: Just for fun, you could simplify that... `awk -F"|" '!a[$1]++' v1`. You still get my vote.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, this is  great

Comment: Read some of Ed Morton's answers to get more insights and learn more than you'll ever need to know about `awk`... https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton

Comment: @ Shen Yudong I'm really sorry,It's my mistake having same value for $1 in all the records. But sometimes 76 change, I'm still in the fence

Answer (score 1):

```
sort --stable --field-separator='|' --key=1,1 -u your_file.csv
```

Note that `--stable` and `-u` together ensure that, if several lines have the same key, the first one will be taken.